# Is there a sensible first order expression meaning that every set in $\omega$ is some set-theoretical natural number?

Tags: set-theory, natural-numbers, proof-theory

Motivation: With the following I want to understand the relationship between the set-theoretical natural numbers **0**,**1**,**2**,... and the set of natural numbers $\omega$ better.

Let **0** := $\emptyset$, **1** := {$\emptyset$}, **2** := {$\emptyset$, {$\emptyset$}}... be the usual set-theoretical natural numbers and let $\omega$ be the set of natural numbers.

For a fixed **n** (for $n \geq 1$), let $\varphi(x)$ be a first-order formula defining the class of sets in **n**. Correct me if I am wrong, but one should now be able to show that

$$\textbf{ZFC} \vdash ((x = \textbf{0} \lor ... \lor x = \textbf{n-1}) \leftrightarrow \varphi(x)).$$

Now let $\varphi(x)$ be a first-order formula defining the class of sets in $\omega$. For bigger and bigger $n$ one should still be able to show (using longer and longer proofs) that

$$\textbf{ZFC} \vdash ((x = \textbf{0} \lor ... \lor x = \textbf{n-1}) \rightarrow \varphi(x)).$$

The analogous result

$$\textbf{ZFC} \vdash (x = \textbf{n} \rightarrow \varphi(x))$$

being obtainable (by metamathematical induction) for any **n** seems to be a sensible way of "proving" that

(1) *The set-theoretical natural numbers are contained in $\omega$.*

It seems however, that not being able to form the infinite disjunction $(x = \textbf{0} \lor x = \textbf{1} \lor ...)$ restricts us to this "collection of proofs" making up the desired statement (1). This leads me to

**Question 1**: Is there a sensible first order expression meaning that every set-theoretical natural number is contained in $\omega$?

The other direction appears to be even worse. It seems that one cannot even give a "collection" $(\varphi_n)$ of first-order expressions indexed by naive natural numbers, s.t.

$$\textbf{ZFC} \vdash \varphi_n$$

is true for all $n$ (e.g. proven by metamathematical induction) and one can view this collection of proofs as a "proof" of

(2) *Every set in $\omega$ is a set-theoretical natural number.*

This leads me to

**Question 2**: Is there a sensible collection of first order expressions indexed by naive natural numbers meaning that every set in $\omega$ is a set-theoretical natural number?

If the answer is yes, then I ask for more in

**Question 3**: Is there a sensible first order expression meaning that every set in $\omega$ is a set-theoretical natural number?

**Remark**: If one just wants to talk about models of **ZFC** inside the universe, then one should be able to find appropriate formulas for all 3 questions using encodings of expressions, a provability predicate, and so on (tell me if I misunderstood this). Assuming the answer to my questions is always no: Is this then another case of "property cannot be checked in the universe (i.e. model of **ZFC** we are in) but can be checked for the models of **ZFC** inside the universe"?

Lastly, thank you for reading all of this.

Comment: The answer to all three is “no”. There is no internal statement expressing “is a set-theoretical natural number” (usually termed a “standard” natural number). You are correct that you can express it externally to a model and can prove that every standard natural number is in $\omega$, but not necessarily the converse. (Models for which the converse holds are called $\omega$-models.)

Comment: You haven't told us what your definition of $\omega$ is.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Doesn't "$x$ is an element of every inductive set" identify the standard natural numbers?

Comment: @RobArthan My $\omega$ is defined using the property Robert mentions.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thank you for the clarifications regarding terminology and making me aware of the fact that "nonstandard" models of ZFC exist. Regarding that something else started to bother me, however. In this [thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40821/existence-of-an-omega-nonstandard-model-of-zfc-from-compactness) the existence of such models is shown with compactness, but isn't it necessary to index the formulas $\varphi$_n with $n \in \omega$ then, since "is standard natural number " can't be expressed? If one does this, the argument doesn't seem to work anymore it seems.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen To clarify: In the other thread, Joel seems to form the union **ZFC** $\cup$ {$\varphi_n \mid n \in \omega$} $\cup$ {$c \in \omega$}. I guess the conditions of the compactness theorem are still met, so there is a model of **ZFC** with some $c \in \omega$ that also satisfies $c \neq n$ for all $n \in \omega$. This would give a contradiction for $n = c$. What am I missing?

Comment: @Hypatius The two $\omega$'s you are writing down are different things. Let's write $\mathbb N$ for the natural numbers in the metatheory, and let's write $\omega$ for the term we define in ZFC (as the minimal inductive set, or what-have-you). Joel is forming the union $\mathsf{ZFC}\cup\{c\ne \mathbf{n}: n\in \mathbb N\}\cup\{c\in \omega\}$, where I use $\mathbf n$ as the same notation for the terms in set theory you define in your original post. Now note each sentence in the union is a sentence in the language of set theory (plus the extra constant symbol).

Comment: @RobertShore That's how we define the natural numbers in set theory, but I believe the OP is asking we can make sense of and prove in some first-order way that that natural numbers consist exactly of the (interpretations of) the terms $\mathbf{n}.$ The compactness argument mentioned above shows we can't.